# getting double digit numbers from an input file accross multiple lines in c

Tags: c, input, graph-theory

I'm currently working on a graph assignmnet in c for uni where we have to make the graph from an adjacency list in an input file but the input file has to have a specific lay out.

```
9
2
7,8 1,6
3
7,3 2,8 0,6
3
8,2 5,6 3,7
3
5,4 4,9 2,7
2
5,1 3,9
4
6,2 4,1 3,4 2,6
3
8,6 7,1 5,2
3
8,7 6,1 0,8
3
7,7 6,6 2,2
```

the top number is the amount of verticies, it is then in ascending order, the amount of edges the vertex has with the next line being the edges which has which vertex the edge goes to and the weight. Incase I explained that terribley the first example is vertex[0] which has 2 edges one going to vertex[7] with a weight of 8 and the other going to vertex[1] with a weight of 6

```
void remove_non_numbers(Graph G, FILE* fp) {
    char line[100];
    int  v, w, count;
    count = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        remove_all_chars(line, ' ');
        remove_all_chars(line, ',');
        if (strlen(line) > 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line) / 2; i++) {
                v = line[i * 2] - '0';
                w = line[(i * 2) + 1] - '0';

                insert_at_front(G, count, v, w);
            }
            count++;
        }
        else {
            if (line[0] == '0') {
                count++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```
void remove_all_chars(char* str, char c) {
    char* pr = str, * pw = str;
    while (*pr) {

        *pw = *pr++;
        pw += (*pw != c);
    }
    *pw = '\0';
}
```

while this currently works fine it obviously does not work if a number has double digits and I'm going to need to use double digits for this assignment. we previously did another graph assignment and I got marked down for code being overly complicated so if there is anything simple I am missing please let me know

Comment: With formatted input this is one case where `fscanf` will should be fairly easy to use. It doesn't care about lines or whitespace (except maybe before the comma). First scan the number of vertices. For each vertex, scan the number of adjacencies. Then for each adjacency `int res = fscanf(fp, "%d ,%d", &vert, &weight);` and so on. It may be important to have the space between `%d` and `,` in the format string.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think the space is needed, but it shouldn't hurt. `%d` will stop at the comma, then the `,` in the format will read it.

Comment: @Barmar true for the data posted, but it makes it space-tolerant. I've seen this as stumbling block in other questions.